# Where do BIRT scripts run?

Tags: birt

Where does actually the BIRT scripts run? Scripts like beforeFactory, fetch, etc.?

In my view, they are rendered at client side, but is it like that? Or is it getting rendered at server side, and only the report view is sent to client side? Firebug console is giving me some clue regarding that, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All BIRT scripts run on server-side (Rhino scripts), within the same JVM as the BIRT engine. This is why they can invoke java objects.

Similarly, when we include a javascript file through "resources" property of a birt report it is **also a server-side script**: don't try for example to include something like jquery here it wouldn't work.

The only exceptions are:

- In a **Text element**, we can set the type to HTML and then add client-side actions between html script tags. This is where we could for example include jquery or any other  client-side framework we like
- From birt 4.3 there is an **event "clientScripts"** where we can put client-side javascript actions. Though i would recommend to make use of the "HTML text element" approach described above instead of this event.
- In a **chart interactivity action**, there is an "Invoke script" option which is actually a client-side javascript